# how to append object array values into an existing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have added a fiddle through that you can get the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ro59fxow/

```
var myFolders = ['abc','bcd','cda']; //these values are dynamic

var a1 = myFolders[0];
var folder = {
                a1:['11'],   //this is giving a1 ,i want here abc
                folder1: ['sss','www'],
                folder2 : ['uvw','xyz']
            }

myFolders.push(folder);
console.warn(myFolders);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you want `abc` there use `a1:a1`. Where first `a1` is key not variable. Your question seems unclear to me.

Comment: Use bracket notation to access the member of an object if the key is stored in a variable `folder[a1] = ["11"];` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w74L2x1r/)

Comment: hi manwal thanks for reply ..i want dynamic key ,a1 =myfolders[0] means a1 is abc but this code is adding a1 place of abc .is there any way to add abc . abc is dynamic can be anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 0):

Merge the second array into the first one is using following code.

```
  Array.prototype.push.apply(myFolders,folder.folder2);
```

output:["abc", "bcd", "cda", "uvw", "xyz"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code should work from what I understood your question.

```
    var myFolders = ['abc','bcd','cda']; //these values are dynamic

    var a1 = myFolders[0];
    console.log(a1);
    var folder = {};
    folder[a1] = ['111']; //use this syntax to evaluate the variable as a key value.

    myFolders.push(folder);
    console.warn(myFolders);
```